# Active Record Nested Association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have an association where I would like to get:

```
Person > has_many :animals > has_many (through animals) :dogs 
       > belongs_to :leash > belongs_to :collar
```

I would like to get all possible `:collar` options so I can check if there is a `collar_id` for that specific `Person`

To check for an instance of `:leash` I did like so (`person` is an instance of a `Person`):

```
person.dogs.where(leash_id: id_of_leash)
```

But I need to now get one level deeper to find if the collar id is found within this specific Person.

Comment: `Person.find(<id of the person>).collars.where(leash_id: <id_of_leash>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> person.dogs.includes(leash: :collar).where("collar.attribute = ?", condition)

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply, would this be `collar.attributes =` or `collar.id =`?

Comment: if you want to check id from collar use `collar.id = 10` for single id else `collar.id IN (ids)` for many ids. `attribute` means any column name from the table collar.

Comment: Hmmm... still not pulling up a result. Will continue to play with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is good practice mixing a query with an iterator but I found this to  work and read clearly:

`person.dogs.to_a.detect{ |d| d.leash.collar.id == collar_id }`